# Cannot call method 'unshift' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var _array=[];
var someint=44;
var somevalue='a string';
var u=[someint];
_array.unshift(u);
_array[u].unshift('somevalue');//*error
```

why does this not work?

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'unshift' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

You've added an element to "_array", and its index will be 0.  However, you're trying to use an array as an index into an array, and that won't work. That is,

```
_array[u]
```

doesn't make sense. Arrays are indexed numerically. Thus the value of that expression is `undefined`, and that explains the error message — you're trying to reference the "unshift" property of the value `undefined`. (Well, `undefined` isn't really a value, but whatever.)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
_array[0].unshift();
```

instead of

```
_array[u].unshift('somevalue');
```

Comment: can i give _array[0] a name?